# How to delete a row in a sqlite database table?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, fmdb

I am using fmdb for managing my database. I could not find any example for deleting a row from a table in fmdb. I tried

```
  NSString *sqlStat=@"DELETE from tableName WHERE id=3";    
  FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:sqlStat];
```

but its not working because when I checked the total number of entries in table, I am getting the same number as before executing the above statement.
So, what is a proper way to delete a row from a table using fmdb?

Comment: How are you determining the number of entries within the table?

Comment: For eg.I am doing
FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:@"select * from tableName"];
and then storing the result in NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 12):

FMDB can be a little finicky if you dont pass in the object as an NSNumber.  This is the supported, and safe way of formatting queries.

```
[db executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM theTable WHERE id = ?", [NSNumber numberWithInt:myObject.id]];
```

Answer (score 11):

You should replace:

... [database executeQuery:sqlStat] ...

with:

... [database executeUpdate:sqlStat];

Also, try adding:

```
[database beginTransaction];
```

before your CRUD block, and:

```
[database commit];
```

after executing an update/delete/insert operation.

;)

Comment: Not sure if this would help anyone else but I'm using sqlite3 from the command line and I issued a `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` before and `COMMIT;` after running my `DELETE` statement.  My first time using the CLI and this is what worked for me.  Thanks for the tip, @Florin.

Comment: Worked with  [database executeUpdate:sqlStat], where sqlStat is "DELETE"

Answer (score 1):

i also ran into the same symptom.
and my problem was i didnt call (and caused "out of memory" error)

```
[db open];
```

be sure to do this to debug your fmdb issues
db.traceExecution=YES;
db.logsErrors=YES;

Answer (score 0):

you need to ensure all the processes

```
NSString *query = @"delete from places where published = 1";
const char *sqlStatement = [query UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // Read the data from the result row
        NSLog(@"result is here");
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
int numberOfEffectedRow = sqlite3_changes(database);
return numberOfEffectedRow; // get number of effected rows
```