# delete row from SQLite database with FMDB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, fmdb

i feel like i have read the docs for FMDB a million times. i am not sure why this code is not working - i have tried the executeUpdate method and the executeMethodWithFormat and their corresponding formats, neither seem to work. _dbArray is an array of dictionarys. these lines return the correct values - if i copy and paste the results and run the query in a terminal, it removes the record fine. am i missing something obvious?

```
- (IBAction)deleteDbEntry:(id)sender {

    // get selected row
    NSInteger row = [_dataTable selectedRow];

    // get the entry number
    NSString *idToDelete = [[_dbArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"entryColumn"];

    // open DB for writing
    if (![db open]) {
        [db open];
    }

    [db executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE entry = ?", idToDelete];

    // close DB
    if ([db open]) {
        [db close];
    }

    [_dataTable reloadData];

    return;
}
```

UPDATE: i have taken your suggestions and it is still not working, and I am not sure why. the opening and closing of the DB is happening elsewhere now (thank you @ccgus), and I am converting a string to an NSNumber (thanks @bryanmac). the `NSLog(@"myNumber is %@", myNumber);` call is returning the correct number, and i can confirm that the deletion is not happening. the `NSLog(@"Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);` is reporting no errors (`Error 0: (null)`). i have also tried:

`[db executeUpdateWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE entry = %@", myNumber];`

and

`[db executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE id = ?", [NSNumber numberWithInt:myNumber]];`

the first seems like it should work, but i have confirmed it does not delete the row. the second errors at me with "incompatible integer to pointer conversion". what am I missing?

```
- (IBAction)deleteDbEntry:(id)sender {

    // get selected row
    NSInteger row = [_dataTable selectedRow];

    // get the entry number
    NSString *idToDelete = [[_dbArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"entryColumn"];

    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString:idToDelete];
    NSLog(@"myNumber is %@", myNumber);

    [db executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE entry = ?", myNumber];
    NSLog(@"Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);

    [_dataTable reloadData];

    return;
}
```

Comment: http://novasys.in/2013/11/22/fmdb-implimentation-ios-applications/

Comment: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/framework-using-fmdb-to-communicate-with-sqlite-databases/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your id an int?

If so, try to pass in an NSNumber to the formatted update statement.

This post can convert NSString to NSNumber.

[How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber)

```
 [db executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE entry = ?", idNumber];
```

Here's a related post:

[How to delete a row in a sqlite database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696044/how-to-delete-a-row-in-a-sqlite-database-table)

Also, make sure you check for errors after your statements:

```
NSLog(@"Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
```

Comment: the ID is a string, and i have tried converting to an NSInteger now, but still no dice. errors return everything is good.

Answer (score 2):

Try printing out your values before the query to make sure that you're getting what you expect.

Also, opening and closing your database so often isn't a good idea- just open it once and assign it to an ivar in your instance, then then close it when you dealloc (or really need to close it).

-gus (the guy who wrote fmdb)

Comment: thanks @ccgus, i was printing the values and they were right. also, i will start opening and closing once each while the program runs - thank you for your tip (and thanks a TON for FMDB (and acorn))!

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
[database beginTransaction];
```

before your CRUD block, and:

```
[database commit];
```

after executing an update/delete/insert operation. Plus `executeUpdate` is correct-

`[database executeUpdate:sqlStat];`

Comment: each statement has an implicit transaction right?  you should only need that if you want a transaction to span calls ...

Comment: not that, I was under the impression that sqlite is transactional. So the `beginTransaction` & `commit` is needed for any update, insert or delete. correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html :: Any command that changes the database (basically, any SQL command other than SELECT) will automatically start a transaction if one is not already in effect.